# thread races and the lock keyword

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

My application has a login area that accesses the database using a thread to do not freeze the UI.

During the login, the system makes some operations to open the main window, and loads the user data (and permissions) in the other thread.

But sometimes, when the database hangs, the system finishes loading before the user is loaded.

And the last operation that the system executes is to apply the permissions (loaded in the thread with the user's data).

I also have a static `User` object that holds the data of the user that makes the login, like its permissions and so on.

The problem occurs when the application gets the data from the static user object before the user is loaded. The permissions are empty and are not applied correctly, causing undesired behavior.

How can I ensure that the static user is loaded, and it only freezes the UI in extreme cases of network/database latency?

I tried using `lock`, but it simply doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
int id = User.GetId(user, password); // returns 0 if the user does not exists

if (id != 0)
{
     new Thread(() => 
     {
          lock (User.CurrentUser) // Try to lock the static CurrentUser object
          { 
              User.LoadCurrentUser(id);  // Loads the CurrentUser object
          }

      }).Start();

      InitializeSystem(); //Make some work on the system. After that, this
                          //will get the User.CurrentUser object to apply the
                          //user's permissions.
  }
```

The method `User.LoadCurrentUser(id);` fills the User.

I know that the lock is not working because I put a `Thread.Sleep(5000);` inside the lock, and the system starts in 2 seconds with the wrong permissions.

Removing the thread is not considered, since it will destroy my UI.

**EDIT**

I'm need to use .Net Framework 4.0 to ensure Windows XP compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

This is the perfect candidate for `await` or chained Tasks.

Await version:

```
async void YourLoginButtonEventHandler() {
    int id = User.GetId(user, password); // returns 0 if the user does not exists

    if (id != 0) {
        await Task.Run(() => User.LoadCurrentUser(id));  // Loads the CurrentUser object
        InitializeSystem();
    }
}
```

Or you could chain them:

```
if (id != 0) {
    Task.Run(() => User.LoadCurrentUser(id))
        .ContinueWith(t => InitializeSystem(), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext);
}
```

Note: Could be a couple of syntax errors.. I typed this straight into here.

What I'm basically trying to show you is that.. you're going about this the hard way. There are newer constructs for this sort of thing.. learn them :)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, my application uses .net framework 4.0 since it need to work in some Windows XP machines. The second solution works with 4.0?

Comment: It does.. however the syntax may be a tiny bit different. For instance, I don't think .NET 4 has `Task.Run(Action)`..

Comment: mmm, the second solution will start InitializeSystem() at the same time of User.LoadCurrentUser(id)? Because I have some UI operations on the InitializeSystem() that cannot freeze.

Comment: UI operations MUST run on the UI Thread if they are updating controls. You can't change that. Using `ContinueWith` and `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` ensures that it fires on the UI thread after the ThreadPool thread has finished. You will need to decouple your data loading from your UI updating so that you don't get cross-thread issues.

Comment: Yes, and I am not performing any UI operarions outside the Dispatcher. In the InitializeSystem method, I have a fade out animation, and the MainWindow fade in. The only thing that I'm running outside the Dispatcher is the DataBase operations. After the MainWindow load (firing the loaded event), the User.CurrentUser is accessed to apply some permissions.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, my english is not good enough to make programming questions :/

Comment: @Guilherme: `async` works on .NET 4.0 / XP if you install Microsoft.Bcl.Async. You'll find `Run` on the `TaskEx` type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Thread.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to block your main thread until the other thread completes or times out.

```
int id = User.GetId(user, password); // returns 0 if the user does not exists

if (id != 0)
{
 var newThread = new Thread(() => 
 {
      lock (User.CurrentUser) // Try to lock the static CurrentUser object
      { 
          User.LoadCurrentUser(id);  // Loads the CurrentUser object
      }

  }).Start();

  InitializeSystem(); 

  if (newThread.Join(someTimeOut))
     // use the User.CurrentUser object to apply the user's permissions.
  else
     // thread timed out, waiting for user load takes too long...

 }
```

Comment: Good answer. Question: The thread timeout occurs instantly or it will lock the Dispatcher for some time while waiting the thread to complete? It seems to timeout instantly if the newThread is not completedwhen the Dispathcer Thread finish its work. If I'm wrong, it can wait how many time before the timeout? Because I cannot simply make a timeout. I need to wait until the user is loaded, does not matter the time that it consumes.

Comment: If the thread has already terminated when Join is called, the method returns immediately. Well, if you say you must wait, then you can set the timeout to some obscure high value...which doesn't make sense. You need to have a rule that if the user doesn't load lets say in 30 seconds, you need to inform the user that there is a problem.

Also the app will continue to perform standard COM and SendMessage pumping even if you block.

Comment: How to set the timeout in this case?

Comment: You pass the timeout in milliseconds as a parameter for Join call:     

    newThread.Join(30000)